# Pass data of arbitrary type between VBA and dll

Tags: dll, com, excel, variant, vba

So I am working on an Excel Project that is going to load a C++ dll using VBA. What I'd like to do is to be able to pass an Excel range with no specific type (data can be numerical or categorical) to the C++ dll (The best way I can describe my Excel range is of the type `variant`).

So the steps probably involve:

1. Load the dll in VBA
2. Send the excel range to dll (The range may contain columns of numbers and/or columns of strings)
3. manipulate the data from excel in the dll file

I am thinking of using excel variant and C++ variant. But it's not clear for me how to use the C++ variant as I couldn't find any good documentations on it.

Another suggestion I received was to ues COM programming.

**My Questions:**

- Could a kind soul possibly provide pointers for me on how to proceed? (e.g. by providing the C++ prototype, and a simple example of how to handle the variant)
- Does anyone know any good documentation/tutorial on using C++ Variants (and perhaps jointly with VBA)?
- Is using COMs preferable to using VARIANTS if speed is an issue?
- Is using the C API an option?

**UPDATE:**

- The size of the ranges I need to manipulate can be large (~ 500,000 rows).
- Speed is a factor, thus, I'd like to avoid unnecessary copying as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you only want to pass data to the dll (and not pointers to actual Excel objects such as `Range`), you have two fundamental options:

1. You have huge data sets and want to avoid copying as much as possible.
   In this case you might want to pass that same `Variant` array you get by calling `Range.Value`. In order to do that, you will have to write a little TLB to reference from VB, in which you would describe your exported C++ function as expecting a `SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)*`. This is because the `Declare` operator will not let you actually pass a SAFEARRAY*.
   The function will look like this:

   ```
   LONG __stdcall ReturnArrLowerBound(SAFEARRAY** ppArr)
   {
       if (ppArr == NULL) return -1;
       SAFEARRAY* pArr = (*ppArr);

       LONG res = 0;
       SafeArrayGetLBound(pArr, 1, &res);

       return res;
   }
   ```

   And the TLB descripion will look like that:

   ```
   [
       uuid(A686B138-D8CE-462e-AEF2-75DA4DBF1C75)
   ]
   library foo
   {
       [
           dllname("TestSafearray.dll")
       ]
       module vb
       {
           [entry("ReturnArrLowerBound")]
           LONG __stdcall ReturnArrLowerBound(SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* ppArr);
       }
   }
   ```

   And your C++ project will obviously include a def file:

   ```
   LIBRARY "TestSafearray"

   EXPORTS
       ReturnArrLowerBound
   ```
2. Your data sets are reasonably sized and you don't mind a little bit of copying.
   Then make your C++ function to accept a mere `int[]` and Declare it in VB as accepting `arr() as Long`. On VB side, allocate an array on `Long`s and copy the elements into it from the `Range.Value` array.

Comment: Thanks! If I am not mistaken, writing the TLB involves COM programming, right? And then does that limit the portability of the application (particularly on linux machines)?

Comment: @SMir No, it does not involve COM programming per se. You only write TLB in order for VB to understand your C++ function signature. Other than that, the function is a plain, non-COM, classic style exported function.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Does using `Variant` allow me to pass mixed types to the DLL? Or it only allows having a single type (be it strings or numbers, etc).

Comment: @SMir Each element of the array is `VARIANT`, so they all have the same type - VARIANT. What each variant contains is completely different question, and yes, they all can contain different actual data. You decide whether or not you want to handle that on the C++ side.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it. I will try to implement it (may take me a few days) and will get back to you if I face any further problems.